# Distilling boolean expresses down to one expression

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I have this boolean expression, which I want to clean up if possible:

```
const isDebug =
  (execArgs.indexOf('--debug') > -1) ||
  (execArgs.indexOf('debug') > -1) ||
  (execArgs.indexOf('--inspect') > -1) ||
  (execArgs.indexOf('--debug=5858') > -1) ||
  (execArgs.indexOf('--debug-brk=5858') > -1);
```

Having to use the extra parentheses and the || is a bit unwieldy.

I could do this instead (I think):

```
const expressions = [
  execArgs.indexOf('--debug') > -1,
  execArgs.indexOf('debug') > -1,
  execArgs.indexOf('--inspect') > -1,
  execArgs.indexOf('--debug=5858') > -1,
  execArgs.indexOf('--debug-brk=5858') > -1
];

const isDebug = !expressions.every(x => !x);
```

Is there a cleaner way to distill expressions like this down? That double negative using [].every is tough to stomach.

Comment: Why not include the `indexOf` call inside the `every` callback?

Comment: yeah that's fine too :)

Answer (score 4):

You didn't go far enough:

```
const expressions = [
  '--debug',
  'debug',
  '--inspect',
  '--debug=5858',
  '--debug-brk=5858'
];

const isDebug = expressions.some(x => execArgs.indexOf(x) > -1);
```

Because `!_.every(x => !_)` is `_.some(x => _)`. Logically at least.

Another option use a regex. You can either build it from the array:

```
const isDebug = new RegExp(expressions.join('|')).test(execArgs);
```

Or from a `RegExp` literal:

```
const isDebug = /--debug|debug|--inspect|--debug=5858|--debug-brk=5858/.test(execArgs)
```

Comment: It may be a bit of a misnomer to name the array `expressions`, maybe `debugArgs` or similar?

Comment: Is some an array helper method like every? didn't know it existed

Comment: They were both added together to ES5. [`every`](https://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.16) [`some`](https://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.17)

Comment: If `execArgs` is an array that `indexOf` check could be simplified by using [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes): `expressions.some(x => execArgs.includes(x));`

Comment: That it could if it is available.

Comment: @DanD. Oops, you're right, ES2016 feature. Plus it's not as nice as I thought, as it can't be passed by ref :(